# MySQL Query needs to bring back rows, not empty results

Tags: mysql, left-join

OK, I've voted to delete my earlier question due to stupidity on my part...

I have the following code:

```
SELECT qnum, id, name, total_staff AS StaffCount, COUNT( q61g ) AS TotalResp, 
(COUNT( q61g ) / total_staff * 100) AS Perc 
FROM tdemog_pfp
LEFT JOIN tresults_pfp ON tdemog_pfp.id = tresults_pfp.q61g
WHERE qnum = 'q61g' AND q60p = '1'
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY name
```

Now, the first part of this query brings back rows from the `tdemog` table, for example it will bring back 5 rows of data each row has an `id` from 1 to 5.  What I need the query to do is then bring back data from the `tresults` table `WHERE q60p = 1` for each of the 5 rows brought back in the first part - like a normal `LEFT JOIN'.

Make sense?

H.

Comment: What results does your current code give you, and what do you want to be different about those results?

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson - Imagine I have two tables, the first table has 5 rows and I want the query to return a result from the second for **all** five rows like a normal `LEFT JOIN` **but** I need that to run WHERE a field in the second table has a certain value.  At the moment, the above query will only return a row if there is data - I need it return all 5 rows from the first table - hope that makes sense?

Comment: Could the GROUP BY in your query be causing issues with your expected results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving part of your `WHERE` clause into your `JOIN` condition:

```
SELECT ...
FROM tdemog_pfp
LEFT JOIN tresults_pfp ON tdemog_pfp.id = tresults_pfp.q61g AND q60p = '1'
WHERE qnum = 'q61g'
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY name
```

If you have a field from your second table in your `WHERE` clause, it will restrict the entire record... but if you put it into your `JOIN` condition, the record from the first table should still be returned even when the record in the second table doesn't meet the additional criteria...

I'm not sure which column belongs to which table... but move whatever columns are in your second table into your `JOIN`.